# Converting RTF to PDF from System

Tags: alfresco

I've createad a rule to transform any file to PDF and copy this one to another folder.

So i can add a file named: "test.rtf" and then the rule create a test.pdf into folder "PDF"..
Till here its ok. If i add a file through alfresco (add content button) it works perfectly...
By the way, on the system that i've developed when i try to add a file then i get my file .rtf correctly in the folder, but the pdf file converted and copied goes without any content...
If i send a rtf file with a table with 10 rows and into the rows i right "testing" then the pdf created goes with the table, and with 10 empty rows...

Someone knows the reason for that?

Im not sure, but maybe when i send the file by the system alfresco starts to convert and copy before completing to create the rtf... someone already got some problem like this one?

Comment: How are you adding the RTF file in your custom system?

Comment: sorry for long time to answer you back... Well, im using WebServiceFactory.getContentService().write to send the file... Probably what happens is that when he start sending, the file is created and activate the rule before finish to send the file...

Comment: You could try some debugging to log when you start writing, when you finish, and when the rule fires? There's a chance things aren't happening in the order you expected...

Comment: havent how to do it... i mean.. when i call webservicefactory.getcontentservice.write im using .jar from alfresco already... and i've not control from alfresco server so i cant debug it in alfresco side...

Comment: You can add logging before the call to write, and after it finishes. For the rules, tweak the [log4j config](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Log4J_Configuration) so you can see about them running

Comment: well, the solution i've got were to create both rtf and pdf into application and then copy to the right folder... im not sure but i think alfresco rules is bugged... :/

Comment: If you can come up with a test case that shows the problem, your best bet is to [report it](http://issues.alfresco.com/). Alas your current question doesn't give enough to go on as a bug report to identify where the problem lies...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're getting in is that Alfresco first creates an empty file with all the meta-data and then updates the file with the associated content.

So you can do 2 things:

1: create a rule which is triggered on update, instead on create/inbound

2: create a rule which triggers a Javascript file, which will do the transformation and will check on the content size.
Hence it's better to create a rule which checks the content on size.
Create a JavaScript file in Data Dictionary/Scripts.
Check the [JavaScript API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#ScriptNode_API)
Something like this:

```
if (document != null && document.size > 0){
document.transformDocument("application/rtf");
}
```